# Does the PHP's define() not work with PDO connection string?

Tags: php, pdo

I was using the PHP's define() to define constants for my PDO connection string, ie. in mysqli.   However, it just didn't seem to work.  I kept getting the error: `Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` when I used the code below:

The PDO connection string would work when I didn't use PHP's define() function to pass in my connection variables.   I'm using PHP 7, MySQL 8, and Apache 2.4.

Problem code below:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL); //check all type of errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // display those if any happen

//Database Connection Constant
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', 'root');
define('DB_NAME', 'gallery_db');

echo DB_PASS;
//phpinfo();

//$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);


try {
    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . "," . DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    if ($dbc) {
        echo "connected";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Working Connection Code:

```php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$dbn = 'gallery_db';

//phpinfo();

try {
    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbn", $username, $password,
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
        ));
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    if ($dbc) {
        echo "connected";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Why does PHP define() not work in PDO's connection string?

Comment: You've included the final comma in the DSN: `DB_NAME.",". DB_USER`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first instance you try this:

`$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.",". DB_USER, DB_PASS);`

This only has two arguments, but PDO needs 3:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
?>
```

https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

What happens is that your password constant works but went into the username part of the connection.

Fix:

```
$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Comment: it does. it shouldn't pollute a Q&A site though

Answer (score -1):

Change

> $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.",". DB_USER, DB_PASS);

to

> $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);